# Why is BytesPerFrame in buffer unexpectedly huge when tapping mic in AVAudioEngine

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, core-audio, avaudioengine

I'm trying to get the buffer data from the microphone.

I was trying to access the `BytesPerFrame` from the buffer value inside the tap block. I tried running the same code on xcode with swift and it gives a normal value. It only gets weird when I ran it in C# with Xamarin.iOS.

I even tried initializing the format with `AudioStreamBasicDescription` with a specific `BytesPerFrame = 2` but the problem is the same.

Here's what it looks like in C#:

```
    var engine = new AVAudioEngine();

    var format = new AVAudioFormat(
        format: AVAudioCommonFormat.PCMInt16, 
        sampleRate: 44100, 
        channels: 1, 
        interleaved: false);

    engine.InputNode.InstallTapOnBus(
        bus: 0,
        bufferSize: 4096, 
        format,
        tapBlock: (buffer, when) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(buffer.FrameCapacity);
                Console.WriteLine(buffer.Format.StreamDescription.BytesPerFrame);

                // other processing
            });

    engine.StartAndReturnError(out var err);
```

This is the swift version:

```swift
    let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: Double(44100), channels: 1, interleaved: false)
    engine.inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 4096, format: format) { (buffer, time) -> Void in
        let bytesPerFrame = buffer.format.streamDescription.pointee.mBytesPerFrame;
        let frameCapacity = buffer.frameCapacity;
    }

    status = .Recording
    try! engine.start()
```

In C#, I expected the `BytesPerFrame` value to be just `2` but what I get is something weirdly huge like `1871587600`

This doesn't happen in swift.

Comment: Can I know why are you wanting to get the buffer data of Microphone? What are you trying to implement?

Comment: A speech processor needs to take samples from the buffer to detect end of speech. Another API also needs raw buffer data (without wav headers) to verify voice ID.

Comment: Can you tell me if the value is from a interleave page? If so then the outcome will be `size must include the whole size for the frame, including interleaved data.` This would explain the large value.

Comment: I can confirm I am running in the same issue, the funny thing is that the value are not event constant between two executions...
I created an issue on the xamarin forms github -> https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9579
Feel free to add missing information there.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like a bug in Xamarin.iOS.
I created an issue on their GitHub there: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/7890.

For future readers that may arrive here in the future, it is likely that the important question is the following one:

> I'm trying to get the buffer data from the microphone.

This is actually possible even though the description data is garbage.

```
private void OnBusTap(AVAudioPcmBuffer buffer, AVAudioTime when)
{
    AudioBuffer audioBuffer = buffer.AudioBufferList[0];
    byte[] data = new byte[audioBuffer.DataByteSize];
    Marshal.Copy(audioBuffer.Data, data, 0, audioBuffer.DataByteSize);
    // do something with data. However, note that you are not on the main thread.
}
```

In my case `OnBusTap` is called 10 times per seconds and DataByteSize is 8820, which perfectly matches the sampleRate of 44100.